# Mate executable as desktop manager in core applications

Tags: lubuntu, mate

In "Default Applications for LXSession", in Lubuntu, there is the tab "Core Applications". There is a field called "Desktop Manager". The entry is 'filemanager' by default, and it uses pcmanfm to control the desktop and icons.
I have installed mate destkop and sometimes things work fine, but sometimes don't. What mate executable should I put in that field in order for it work without further problems? As for now, that field is left blank.

Comment: the filemanager in Mate is Caja

Comment: is there some parameter to add to caja? with lubuntu, the field contained the value 'pcmanfm --desktop'

Comment: removing nemo (cinnamon's file manager) seemed to have solved the issue

Comment: @ProgAndPlay If you found a solution to your problem please add an explanation as an answer below and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like nemo (cinnamon's file manager) what getting in the way (according to what I could see in 'ps -fax' listings. So removing nemo seemed to solve the issue.